# Django HTML Form Array Store in DB

Tags: python, html, arrays, django, post

I did a django app 2 years ago in 1.5 and am looking to update it using 1.7 (changed servers and old app wont run).
I have a HTML form that contains some dynamic data (lines added) the result stored in an HTML array on POST. problem is I can't access the stored array in django. I want to JSON encode and store it in the Database.

I did this once with a simpler HTML array using `get_post_dict` with django 1.5 but am just trying to use django again but with 1.7.
I tried `request.POST.getlist`. 
My HTML array looks like this on POST

```
invoice_1[items_attributes][description] u'Here Goes'
invoice_1[items_attributes][formatted_quantity]u'2'
invoice_1[items_attributes][sort_order] u'1'
invoice_1[items_attributes][category_id]    
invoice_1[items_attributes][sample]
invoice_1[items_attributes][unit] 
invoice_1[items_attributes][formatted_price] 
invoice_2[items_attributes][sort_order] u'2'
invoice_2[items_attributes][category_id] 
invoice_2[items_attributes][description] u'Another Item'
invoice_2[items_attributes][sample]         
invoice_2[items_attributes][formatted_price]        
invoice_2[items_attributes][unit] u'each'
invoice_2[items_attributes][formatted_quantity]

or
invoice[items_attributes][1][description] = u'Sample Item'
invoice[items_attributes][1][sort_order] = u'1'
invoice[items_attributes][1][formatted_quantity] = u'32'
invoice[items_attributes][1][formatted_price] = u'81'
invoice[items_attributes][2][unit] = u'each'
invoice[items_attributes][2][sample] = u''
invoice[items_attributes][2][sort_order] = u'2'
invoice[items_attributes][2][formatted_quantity] = u'22'
invoice[items_attributes][2][description] = u'Another Item'
invoice[expenses_attributes][3][description] = u'Gas Purchase'
invoice[expenses_attributes][3][rate] = u'3000'
invoice[expenses_attributes][3][quantity] = u'1'
invoice[expenses_attributes][3][amount] = u'3000'
invoice[items_attributes][2][formatted_price] = u'41'
invoice[expenses_attributes][3][sample] = u''
```

The old code as I said used simpler arrays e.g

```
invoice_0[name_and_description]
invoice_0[quantity]
invoice_0[price]
invoice_0[unit]
```

I was able to use `get_post_dict(request.POST, 'invoice_0')` but now I am at a loss as to how to pull this off.
Notes: The HTML form is not my design but an improvement over the form used on the old app from 2yrs.

Comment: Can you show the code that is POSTing that? Is it coming from a JS script?

Comment: Not coming from JScript, standard POST from form.